# Retrieve Phone Number in Phone Authentication of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have Main Activity and Next Activity. In Main Activity, I use phone authentication of `firebase`. Once it is successful, I am redirecting the user to Next Activity. In Next Activity, I want the user's phone number which he put in Main Activity. I used `getIntent` to pass the phone number, but it does not works when I close and reopen my app again as I am opening Next Activity and not Main Activity on reopening after successful authentication. I used `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber()` 
but it does not work as well. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to store the phone number in the Main Activity and then retrieve it in in the Next Activity. As the value will be stored in the file, you can use it again when you re-open the activity.

For saving the phone number:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("PHONE_NUMBER", "XXX-XXXX-XXXX");
    editor.apply();
```

For retrieving the phone number:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPreferences.getString("PHONE_NUMBER", "RETURNED_VALUE_IF_KEY_DOES_NOT_EXIST");
```

For more information about SharedPreferences:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: I was just doing that

Comment: Normally getPhoneNumber() should work, however Firebase Auth may or may not give you phone number/ e-mail address if you have multiple sign-in methods activated or multiple accounts with an e-mail activated etc. so SharedPreferences may be a better approach in this case. Also, if you think this answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: This approach if for the first time i think works good but when user uninstall app then Install again. So, when we want to retrieve phoneNumber, this is not work.

Comment: var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String pn = user!.phoneNumber.toString();
    print("user_phone_number " + pn);

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActivity, make sure to pass the phone number like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
i.putStringExtra("phoneNumber", YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Then replace "YOUR_EDIT_TEXT" with the edit text that the user put the phone number in.

Then in your NextActivity, to get the phone number, use this code:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String phoneNumber = i.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
```

So now the phone number is stored in the variable phoneNumber.

To sign in with that phone mumber, see [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).

Hope this helps!

Comment: As i mentioned in my question,i did that but the value does not persist on closing the app

Comment: yes because you have to add the phone number to firebase as the link i gave you explains. and then when the user exits and gets on the app again, you can retrieve the phone via firebase. If you want it locale on the device and not on a server, then use shared prefs

Comment: i have done that

Comment: you could store the phone number to the server on the firebase realtime database. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) should help you

Answer (score 0):

It returns a Phone number if it is stored or return null. So please check are you getting phone number?

> public abstract String getPhoneNumber ()
>
> Returns the phone number of the user, as stored in the Firebase
>   project's user database, or null if none exists. This can be updated
>   at any time by calling updatePhoneNumber(PhoneAuthCredential).
>
> This field will be automatically populated on account creation if the
>   AuthCredential used on signInWithCredential(AuthCredential) contained
>   such information. This phone number is displayed in the Users section
>   of the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simple trick

*save the input(i.e. the phone number) in a string in Main Activity

*on a successful authentication pass that saved number to the next activity

Comment: doesn't work,already tried.Values gets lost on closing the app,same thing happens with sharedprefernces.

Comment: edit your question( show your codes) and drop me a comment when you are done